# What is the function of aapt.exe in android?

Tags: android, windows

When i list the running processes under windows 7, about 20 aapt.exe processes are showing and they take a lot of memory. This happens when android studio is opened. I am always forced to exit android studio and open it again. How can remedy the situation while leaving android studio running? And what is the function of aapt.exe? I have android studio 1.2.1.1.

Answer (score 8):

`aapt.exe` is the Android Asset Packaging Tool (aapt). It's designed to take your application resource files, such as the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and other XML files used for every "Activity" in your Android app, and compile them. An `R.java` is generated so you can reference your resources from your Java code.

[More details here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

About the second question:

> How can remedy the situation while leaving android studio running?

I have also same issue and a lot of aapt.exe wich still running even all emulators and others android development tools are stopped.

Mi solution to stop all them:

```
Taskkill /T /F /IM aapt.exe
```

in cmd or a .bat file

Answer (score 2):

It is used for compiling the Android resource files and generate the R.Java file for referring the resource directly into the Java code.